# Get pagination to follow "Back" / "Forward" buttons with window.history.pushstate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a page of results with pagination work seamless with the back and forward buttons. If you click the "Next" button and go to page 2. I need the back button to navigate back to the first page of the results and so on. Same would go for the "jump to page" buttons. If the "active" page is page 3, and the back button is clicked I would need the "active" button to follow.

I was able to get this working with a page number appended to the url:

```
window.history.pushState({path:updateurl},'',updateurl,);
```

But can't seem to get it working with the pagination or currentPage. I was also trying to work in a:

```
window.history.replaceState()
```

On every pagination click to see if I could rewrite the history to just got back to the last state. But no luck.

I understand this is a bit complicated.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/destrada/zqobjcun/1/) of my project.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a `popstate` eventlistener in your fiddle. When user click the back or forward button in the browser, this event will fire, and you can use `document.location` or `event.state` to set your page.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  // assuming you only have 1 query
  const index = document.location.search.split("=")[1];
  // set your currentPage
  setCurrentPage(index);
};
```

See the MDN reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: What are you doing with setCurrentPage? Even if that is supposed to be currentPage I am getting errors when the back button is hit.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification, `setCurrentPage(index)` is a function you'd have to implement by yourself, where given the `index` (currentPage) it will toggle the correct divs. I think it is outside the scope of the question -- the main thing is that you'd need to use `popstate` to update your pagination.